# Computationally efficient solution for the measure of central tendency minimizing Lp loss for p > 1

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory, oc.optimization-and-control

We know that the measure of central tendency that minimizes the Lp loss is $\min_c \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i - c|^p$

For $p=1$ (L1 loss), this is the median. For $p=2$ (L2 loss), this is the mean. Both of these have solutions which are computationally efficient to find. Is there a similar computationally efficient method for finding the general Lp estimator?

More specifically, we focus in $p>1$ as $0<p<1$ is non-convex. I imagine a closed form solution would be more efficient than naive search.

Comment: what is the closed form for the median?

Comment: @mathworker21 - I made an error in the post. Apologies. My intention was computationally efficient and translated that to closed-form.